# Choose last element from div dropdown

Tags: php, ajax

I have dropdown list with values from a database. I'm trying to select the last element value using `ajax` and change the value by default to the last. I've tried multiple solutions, but my scripts still returns an empty value.

### HTML

```
<div class="three wide field">
    <label>Page number</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown" id="dropdown-pages">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="{{ filters.page }}">
    <div class="default text">Page number</div>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
            {% for page in 1..count_pages %}              
            <div class="item" id="example" data-value="{{ page }}">{{ page }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### AJAX

```
$('#lastPage').click(function () {
    var lastValue = $('#page').last()
    alert(lastValue);

    $('#search').submit();
});
```

Comment: Pretty Unclear whats the issue you were facing over here

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over an array or object, you can set the id for your div.item individualy.

Then you should have access to your last item with jquery by id

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code:

```
$("select option:last").attr("selected","selected");
```

try above code for select last option in dropdown using jQuery...

Thanks

Comment: This won't work as your expectation OPs question doesn't contains `select` element. Please read the question first carefully. I'm not downvoting your answer but it seems you were clever enough what I'm pointing out

Comment: thanks, for your answer but if you mention to my html code that is another type of dropdown